# How to speed up deep learning research?

Tags: deep-learning

I am working on multimedia enhancement tasks using deep generative neural networks. I only have access to one 11 GB GPU, and I really want to speed up my research. I am currently using a deep residual GAN, all GPU memory is occupied with a batch size of 8.

I want to experiment with using different architectures but every single trial takes at least 3 days. I have an idea about comparing multiple models in parallel, by reducing the model sizes, batch size or the input size. Once I find the best performing model, I can scale it up. Is this a bad idea? What are some other methods?

Comment: Try training your models on google colab and kaggle kernels. In that way you can train multiple models simultaneously. Also make sure you do checkpointing, because they renew the resources after 8 hours.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to automate so that training restarts after 8 hours and loads the saved model?

Comment: As of now not possible.